# In python, how can I type hint an input that is not str or bytes and is a sequence?

Tags: python, python-typing

In python, how can I type hint an input that is not str or bytes and is a sequence?
I have a function that I want to accept a sequence but not accept a string or bytes input. But this code allows in str and bytes:

```
import typing

def validate(input_data: typing.Sequence) -> None:
    # implementation that validate that input data meets expected constraints
    #one can ignore the implementation
    pass
```

Comment: You can't.  You'll have to check for that at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can do this by creating a Sequence protocol that implements the sequence interface, and by making the contains method ingest object, str and bytes classes will not implement the new protocol.
Answer from: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/256#issuecomment-1687374072

- [str `__contains__` is incompatible with this definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/4ca5ee98df5654d0db7f5b24cd2bd3b3fe54f313/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L564)
- [bytes `__contains__` is incompatible with this definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/4ca5ee98df5654d0db7f5b24cd2bd3b3fe54f313/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L684)

Here's the code:

```
import typing

_T_co = typing.TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)


class Sequence(typing.Protocol[_T_co]):
    """
    if a Protocol would define the interface of Sequence, this protocol 
    would NOT allow str/bytes as their __contains__ is incompatible with the definition in Sequence.
    methods from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection
    """
    def __contains__(self, value: object, /) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    def __getitem__(self, index, /):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[_T_co]:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __reversed__(self, /) -> typing.Iterator[_T_co]:
        raise NotImplementedError

def validate(input_data: Sequence) -> None:
    # implementation that validates that input data meets expected constraints
    #one can ignore the implementation
    pass

def validate_typed_sequence(input_data: Sequence[int]) -> None:
    # implementation that validates that input data meets expected constraints
    #one can ignore the implementation
    pass
```

Comment: Interesting that in typeshed, this seems to be how `collections.Sequence` is annotated: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/a094aa09c2aa47721664d3fdef91eda4fac24ebb/stdlib/typing.pyi#L511

Comment: Aha! But typeshed breaks Liskov with their annotations for `str`: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/a094aa09c2aa47721664d3fdef91eda4fac24ebb/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L592 and just inherits from `Sequence`

Comment: Right but the python interpreter imposes this behavior too. x in y where y is a str uses `__contains__`. An exception is raised:
`>>> 1 in "abc"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`
and `>>> None in b"abc"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: Sure, but that's sort of besides the point. Basically, as type annotated, `str` and `bytes` are *already* not proper subtypes of `collections.abc.Sequence`

Comment: Do you think that that is in error? If so, how about you submit an issue to typeshed?

Comment: I don't think it's an error, it's a conscious choice which is why they use `# type: ignore`